# Remove Brackets and Text Between Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, replace

I have a long string with many different brackets/braces/parenthesis ({{...}},{...},[...], [[...]], <...>) with some being inside others.

I would like to use JS to remove these brackets and whatever text/etc is inside them (except for [[...]] that are not inside other brackets, in this case I would like only the brackets removed).

**Here is an example of the type of string I'm working with:**

> {{pp-move-indef}} {{Taxobox | name = Red panda | status = VU | status_system = iucn3.1 | status_ref = | image = RedPandaFullBody.JPG | regnum = [[Animal]]ia | phylum = [[Chordate|Chordata]] | classis = [[Mammal]]ia | ordo = [[Carnivora]] | subordo = [[Caniformia]] | infraordo = [[Arctoidea]] | superfamilia = [[Musteloidea]] | familia = [[Ailuridae]] | genus = Ailurus | genus_authority = [[Frederic Cuvier|F. Cuvier]], 1825 | species = A. fulgens | binomial = Ailurus fulgens | binomial_authority = [[Frederic Cuvier|F. Cuvier]], 1825 | range_map = Cypron-Range Ailurus fulgens.svg | range_map_caption = Red panda range | subdivision_ranks = Subspecies | subdivision = A. f. fulgens
> A. f. styani }}
>
> The red panda (Ailurus fulgens, lit. "shining cat"), is a small [[arboreal]] [[mammal]] native to the eastern [[Himalayas]] and southwestern [[China]]{{IUCN |assessors=Wang, X., Choudhry, A., Yonzon, P., Wozencraft, C., Than Z. |year=2008 |id=714 |taxon=Ailurus fulgens |version=2010.4 |downloaded=26 June 2010}} and related to [[raccoon]]s, [[skunk]]s and [[weasel]]s. It is the only extant species of the genus Ailurus and the family [[Ailuridae]]. Slightly larger than a [[domestic cat]], it has reddish-brown fur, a long, shaggy tail, and a waddling gait due to its shorter front legs. It feeds mainly on [[Bamboo shoot|bamboo]], but is [[omnivorous]] and may also eat eggs, [[bird]]s, [[insect]]s, and small [[mammal]]s. It is a [[solitary animal]], mainly [[Nocturnality|active from dusk to dawn]], and is largely [[Sedentary lifestyle|sedentary]] during the day.

**Desired Result**

> The red panda (Ailurus fulgens, lit. "shining cat"), is a small arboreal mammal native to the eastern Himalayas and southwestern China and related to raccoons, skunks and weasels. It is the only extant species of the genus Ailurus and the family Ailuridae. Slightly larger than a domestic cat, it has reddish-brown fur, a long, shaggy tail, and a waddling gait due to its shorter front legs. It feeds mainly on Bamboo shoot|bamboo, but is omnivorous and may also eat eggs, birds, insects, and small mammals. It is a solitary animal, mainly Nocturnality|active from dusk to dawn, and is largely Sedentary lifestyle|sedentary during the day.

Comment: Please post the approaches you have tried so far. What did not work and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Tried `string.replace(some regex,'')` but don't know enough to get the desired results.

Can this be done with `.replace()`?

Comment: Ah, so the "nested brackets" will always be consecutive? I.e. it will always be `{{...}}` but never `{...{...}...}`?

Comment: I believe that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
function removeBrackets(input) {
    return input
        .replace(/{.*?}/g, "")
        .replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "")
        .replace(/<.*?>/g, "")
        .replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "");
}
```

Comment: This will produce broken results for `{{...}}` or any other nested sets of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this builds on @Joseph Lennox's suggestion above.

```
function removeBrackets(input) {
    return input
        .replace(/{+.*?}+/g, "")
        .replace(/\[\[|\]\]/g, "")
        .replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
}
```

... the + let's us absorb {{ and }}, etc.

Comment: *"with some being inside others"* might also mean that the input can be `{...{...}...}`. But the OP has to clarify that.

Comment: Sadly, JS's regex lacks recursive support making this impossible via regex. The question asker wasn't very clear/still isn't, so I doubt anyone is jumping in this boat.

Comment: I added an example, I hope it clarifies the question.

Comment: I've updated the response to match your example.  It appears to produce the desired results for me.